# In VUE 3, how to insert a HTML code containing @click event to a already rendered page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a VUE3 application with Django (Python) in the backend. I am trying to add a "div" to a DataTable cell with Javascript. See the code below:

```
let myTable = $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable()
myTable.cell(vm.table_index, 12).data(`

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-around mx-1">
        ${vm.counter_selected}
        <a @click.prevent="unapplyCounter(index, part_number)"
           class="text-danger"
           id="assign_counter">
            <i class="fas fa-backspace"></i>
        </a>
    </div>

`)
```

As you can see, the "a" element has a Vue @click event in it.
When this code is added to the page, it shows as an attribute, and VUE does not detect it. The screenshot below shows how the HTML is right after the code above is applied:

[image]

What am I missing in order to make VUE3 recognize the @click event?

Comment: Vue does pre-processing on its templates in order to make things like `@click` and other reactivity features work. When you manually add something to the DOM after render, you completely bypass this step, meaning Vue won't recognize any handlers on the added element(s).

Comment: I'll also note that, in general, making these sorts of manual DOM manipulations outside of Vue is generally a recipe for obscure bugs and a rough time, and should *usually* be avoided. 99% of the time you can use a Vue feature to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @zcoop98, thanks for the feedback. This is exactly what I thought the reason was. Basically, once rendered, VUE does not recognize the new manually added event. You mentioned templates. Is there any way I can do it using VUE templates? Or somehow, manually in my javascript code, tell VUE re-check all the handlers on the page?

Comment: A method to accomplish this would be to use a normal event handler on the element after it has been mounted to the page using `.addEventListener(`. You should only consider this option as a last resort.

Comment: @RoboKozo, I did exactly this to solve the problem, but I would like to know if there is any Vue scope solution. I read about "dynamic components" in Vue, but I could not find a way to change them individually as I have a table with 17k rows (each row, a component). Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: A dynamic component is just a way of deciding which component to use during runtime. If you don't already have a component, it won't help you.